# embedded canvas app + Issue with patch not updating the null values

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-modeldriven

I have created an embedded canvas app in model driven CRM Form.

I am updating my crm form values through the embedded canvas app -

I added the below formula on "OnDataRefresh" property of "ModelDrivenFormIntegration" so that data is updated when i hit Save on CRM Form -

```
Patch('DataSourceName', ModelDrivenFormIntegration.Item,
{
   'Attribute 1' :Value(DataCardValue3.Text),
   'Attribute 2' :Value(DataCardValue4.Text),

}
);
```

This works fine when i update the value of the fields such as from '600' to '700'. However the issue arises when i remove the values from the field such as from ''600" to blank " ". When the field value is blank, it does not update the  ModelDrivenFormIntegration.Item and shows the previous value again as soon as i hit Save.

Also tried turning on "Formula Level Error Management", it did not work, also with this setting on my formulas stopped working

Kindly suggest any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because PowerApps dont recognise your "" as a Null or Empty Value like you expect it.

As an [Microsoft  Post](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/new-feature-error-handling-and-writing-null-values-to-databases/) mentioned you have to activate **Experimental Features** for writing NULL Values to your Database.

**Edit:**
Okay so after reading some threads Patch with NULL resolving into Error that the new Value isn't updated, some recommend to change the Function from `PATCH()` to `UPDATEIF()`

```
UpdateIf(
         ValueList, 
         LookUp(ValueList, PrimaryKeyColumn = "A specific value"), /* <-- Use LookUp formula to find the specific record you want to update */ 
         {NullValueColumn = 1}
)
```

I'm refering to the [Documentation of UPDATE and UPDATEIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-update-updateif)

Comment: Hey thank you for responding. I tried activating "Formula Level Error Management" but after this setting is on, my save functionality stops working completely. I also tried DataCard.Update = Coalesce( TextInput.Text, Blank() ). but even this does not work. Kindly suggest

Comment: Please check my Edit

Comment: If this fields a String: Try replacing " " with BLANK()

Comment: Hey thank you so much. with some tweeks the solution worked